# Twig loop grouping divs

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig

I want to populate a twig page with information stored in the database. I use a loop to make multiple divs containing different entries of the same tables. The only problem is that I want to group the divs by4.. and I can't stop the loop when I reach the fourth step. In the end i get a big colon of divs.
Can anyone please tell me how to group the divs by 4?

This is my twig template:

```
<form method="POST" id="form-book">
    <section id="portfolio" class="container main">    
        <ul class="gallery col-4">             
           {% for type in typeandrooms %}
           {% for t, room in type %}
           <li>
               {% if t == 0 %}
               <div class="preview">
                   {% set var_id = 'bundles/twnelo/images/portfolio/thumb/item' %}
                   {% set var_id = var_id ~ room.getType.id %}
                   {% set var_id = var_id ~ '.jpg' %}
                   <img src="{{ asset(var_id) }}">
                   <div class="overlay">
                   </div>
               </div>
               <div class="desc">
                   <h5> {{ room.getType.name }} </h5>
                   <strong>Beds: </strong>Double bed<br/>
                   <strong>Available rooms: </strong> {{ type|length }} <br/>
                   <strong>Prices: </strong> {{ room.getPrice }} <br/>
                   <button type = "submit" name="singleapartment" value = "{{ room.getType.id }}" class="btn btn-success btn-small">Book a room !</button>
               </div> 
               {% endif %}
           {% if loop.index % 4 == 0 and loop.index > 0 %}
           </li>
           Al 4-lea pas
           <li>
           {% endif %} 
           </li> 
       {% endfor %}
       {% endfor %}
       </ul>
   </section>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Problem is solved. This is the new template:

```
<form method="POST" id="form-book">
    <section id="portfolio" class="container main">    
        <ul class="gallery col-4">          

            {% for rooms in typesandrooms %}                  

                {% for room in rooms %}
                    {% if loop.index == 1 %}
                        <li>    
                            <div class="preview">
                                {% set var_id = 'bundles/twnelo/images/portfolio/thumb/item' %}
                                {% set var_id = var_id ~ room.getType.id %}
                                {% set var_id = var_id ~ '.jpg' %}
                                <img src="{{ asset(var_id) }}">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                    </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="desc">
                                <h5> {{ room.getType.name }} </h5>
                                <strong>Facilities: </strong>{% for facility in room.getFacilities %} {% if loop.index < 4 %} {{ facility.getFacility }}; {% endif %} {% endfor %}<br/>
                                <strong>Available rooms: </strong> {{ rooms|length }} <br/>
                                <strong>Prices: </strong> {{ room.getPrice }} Lei <br/>
                                <button type = "submit" name="singleapartment" value = "{{ room.getType.id }}" class="btn btn-success btn-small">Book a room !</button>
                            </div>
                        </li>       
                    {% endif %}

                {% endfor %}

            {% endfor %}

        </ul>
    </section>
</form>
```

Comment: why are you one time checking "loop.index" and one time "t" ?

Comment: t is to read only once, to avoid duplicate data. and loop.index is to make the "step" on every 4th iteration, in this case applying the <li></li> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to open the first row right before the loop.

```
 {% for type in typeandrooms %}
+  <li>
 {% for t, room in type %}
-  <li>
```

And close the last one right after

```
    {% endif %} 
    -  </li> 
    {% endfor %}
    + </li>
{% endfor %}
```

And given this line `{% if t==0 %}` I reckon you'll need to use a counter instead of `index.loop`. Else you could end up with less than 4 room per list row. The best practice would be to parse the array first in your controller and remove the rooms with t==0 then just remove the `{% if t==0 %}` line in your twig template and it'll work with `index.loop`, you want to keep the logic in twig to a minimum.

Comment: i modified the controller as you told me. things are more simple now. I dont use associative arrays twice, i only have an array of rooms, this means an array of arrays. The problem is now solved. i will post the code in case anyone else needs to see the solution.